# Issue with small signal ML TED with low RRC excess bandwidth

Tags: digital-communications, bpsk, synchronization, symbol-timing

I have a simple BPSK system using RRC TX & RX filters with 10% excess bandwidth with a receiver that uses a symbol synchronizer of the common type consisting of a polyphase filter bank (performing simultaneous matched filtering and resampling), a PI loop, and a timing error detector (TED). (i.e. pretty much what gnuradio's symbol sync block does).

I was having an issue testing my receiver in the presence of a rather large symbol rate mis-match between tx & rx (~1500 ppm) and noticed the following behavior:

Let TED1 = The small signal ML TED (Signal times Slope Maximum Likelihood solution approximation as used in the gnuradio symbol sync block)

TED2 = The large signal ML TED (Signum times Slope Maximum Likelihood solution approximation as used in the gnuradio symbol sync block)

I found that TED1 failed to lock while TED2 successfully locked. If bring the symbol rate error down to say ~100ppm then I can get TED1 to start working.

If I instead increase my RRC excess bandwith on tx/rx to 35%, both TEDs work at the ~1500ppm symbol rate error.

It makes sense to me that as I increase the RRC excess bandwidth that the performance of the symbol synchronizers improves in general (I understand from previous answers that increasing the excess bandwidth reduces self noise by reducing zero-crossing jitter).

However it is not super clear to me why the performance of so called large signal ML ted works while the small signal ML ted does not in this case. Is it because the large signal ML ted is essentially removing some of the aforementioned jitter in the zero crossings by using the signum instead of the actual value and thus improving the performance? Any other insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @AndyWalls wrote the GNU Radio timing blocks I believe so hopefully he sees this and has further insight to your question.

Comment: Note too that if this is the Gardner TED, I found that performance is superior when using the signal prior to RRC filter in the receiver. Although the signal after the RRC filter has no ISI at the correct symbol locations (anssuming no other distortion such as multipath) but has a significantly larger ISI at the zero crossings. (Larger timing jitter).

Comment: I can't fully answer right now.  The ML approximation TEDs are basically approximations of the tanh()*derivative expression given in equation 5 of this paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3234710_Multirate_digital_filters_for_symbol_timing_synchronization_in_software_defined_radios

I recommend you simulate the TED S-Curves for your scenarios to ensure you have the correct TED gain set for the Symbol Sync block.  The simulated S-Curves might also provide other insights:
https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gr-digital/examples/demod/symbol_sync_test_float_ted_gain.m

Comment: @AndyWalls Yeah I did simulate the S-curve to set the ted gain, I will post that tomorrow, though I didn't find any great insight. The only thing I have right now is that the small signal approximation is essentially a non data-aided, non decision directed estimate as compared to the large signal approx being non data aided, decision directed estimate. This indicates to me that the small signal approximation could be suffering from the self noise problem from low rrc bandwidths which the large signal approx sees less of by using the signum....not sure that entirely explains it though.